# acusativo y dativo: Pronombres

Tags: pronombres

I am currently learning for my Spanish exam and I can't understand part of the following solution:

A: “He escrito un poema y **se lo** he enseñado a mi profesor de literatura”

B: “¿Y cómo ha reaccionado tu profesor? ¿”Qué **te** ha dicho?

A: “**Me** ha felicitado porque **le** ha gustado muchísimo”

In the last sentence, why is the "le" correct. To my understanding there should be an *acusativo*, and because we can only use "le" in the *acusativo* for a male person (not objects) it should be a "lo".

Does anyone know if the "le" is correct and if so, why exactly?
Thanks in advance, really apreciate the help from this forum

Comment: From your name and location, I make an educated guess that you might know German: if this is true, think of "**ihm** hat das Gedicht gefallen". **Ihm** is dative and refers to the professor: it works the same way in Spanish. Otherwise, see my answer.

Comment: *"Le ha gustado muchísimo"* = "To-him it-has-pleased a lot" (the implicit subject is *"el poema"*).

Comment: @wimi thanks a lot, I indeed translated it but I don't really see where the substitution of the "le poema" is. In german: 
"Sie hat mir gratuliert weil ES ihr sehr gefallen hat". I don't see where we have the "it" (= el poema) in the spanish sentence.

Comment: @MikeHeimlich you are right, "el poema" is completely omitted (no substitution). We often omit the subject in Spanish. I guess you can equate it with "- Wie hast du das Gedicht gefunden? - Gut, hat mir gefallen" where "es" is omitted. This is (as far as I know) very colloquial in German but standard in Spanish.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, just as we (most of the time) omit all the yo, tú, él. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Le** refers to *tu profesor* in your sentence, and not to *un poema*:

- *A mi profesor* **le** ha gustado muchísimo el poema.

Verbs like [gustar](https://dle.rae.es/gustar) with this meaning are intransitive (DLE):

> 3. intr. Agradar, parecer bien.

*Intransitive* means that the person who likes something is the (dative) indirect object, not the (accusative) direct object. The thing that is liked (*un poema*) is always the subject in such sentences. Note that in Spanish grammar, we do not usually talk about "accusative" (we call this *direct object*, or *complemento directo*) or "dative" (we call this *indirect object*, or *complemento indirecto*).

Answer (score 1):

Spanish is not like English.

example: Me gusta esto: subject esto, me = to me

I like this.

While in English the action is done by one, in Spanish is done by the English direct object.